# NodeJS accessing Google SpreadSheets

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I made this code (index.js):

```
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet')
const credentials = require('./credentials.json')
const { promisify } = require('util')

const docId = '1lrGt8C9gjrabhVjGYoFh-q40rLuRHz6u9vRZqVeLG-c'
const accessSheet = async() => {
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(docId)
    await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(credentials)
    const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)()
    const worksheet = info.worksheets[0]
    const rows = await promisify(worksheet.getRows)({

    })
    rows.forEach(row => {
        console.log(row.Title)
    })
}
accessSheet()
```

I'm trying to connect my code with a google spreadsheet. For the connection, I'm using node.js, but I'm getting this error message.

```
C:\Users\rodrigo.pasini\Desktop\robo_grpr\node_modules\google-spreadsheet\lib\GoogleSpreadsheet.js:101
    this.jwtClient = new JWT({
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'jwtClient')
    at useServiceAccountAuth (C:\Users\rodrigo.pasini\Desktop\robo_grpr\node_modules\google-spreadsheet\lib\GoogleSpreadsheet.js:101:20)
    at node:internal/util:360:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at useServiceAccountAuth (node:internal/util:346:12)
    at accessSheet (C:\Users\rodrigo.pasini\Desktop\robo_grpr\index.js:9:47)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rodrigo.pasini\Desktop\robo_grpr\index.js:19:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your showing script and your error message, I'm worried that the current version of google-spreadsheet you are using might be different from your showing script. So, in this answer, I would like to propose a sample script converted from your showing script using the latest version of google-spreadsheet.

When I check the latest version of google-spreadsheet, it seems that it's 3.2.0. So, first, please check the version of google-spreadsheet you are using. And, please install the latest one.

When your script is modified for using with the latest one (v3.2.0), it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require("google-spreadsheet");

const creds = require('./credentials.json');
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('###'); // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.

const accessSheet = async () => {
  await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds);
  await doc.loadInfo();
  const worksheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0];
  const rows = await worksheet.getRows();
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    console.log(row.Title);
  });
};
accessSheet();
```

#### Reference:

- [node-google-spreadsheet](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: @ Tanaike, thanks for your support. I´m using the last version of google-spreadsheet. After using your suggest, now I'm getting an extended error message. I will show in the answer below.

Comment: @Rodrigo Fiad Pasini Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, from your showing message, I cannot confirm the error message. But, in your situation, please confirm whether your Google Spreadsheet is shared with the email of the service account. Because I cannot confirm about this in your question. When the service account doesn't have permission for accessing Spreadsheet, an error occurs. Please be careful about this. And, when I tested this script, no error occurred. Please don't worry about the modified script.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error message:
FetchError: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.googleapis.com

Comment: @Rodrigo Fiad Pasini Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your reply, unfortunately, I cannot understand your situation. But, can you confirm the following points? 1. In this case, the service account is required to be used. Your `credentials.json` is for the service account? 2. When you want to access your Spreadsheet using the service account, please share it with the service account. Unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script, no error occurs. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I believe that the first error that was appearing was because of the proxy in the company where I work. I still haven't been able to solve that part.
On my private computer, I had this last error because I had no internet access. Sorry about that. Now it's working perfectly.

Comment: @Rodrigo Fiad Pasini Thank you for replying and testing it again.